# Paypal log error

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, paypal-standard

I am currently trying to figure out why paypal is not working properly.

I found this error in the logs.

```
2017-06-22T02:18:31+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array (
[url] => https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
[getPalDetails] => Array
    (
        [METHOD] => getPalDetails
        [VERSION] => 94.0
        [USER] => ****
        [PWD] => ****
        [SIGNATURE] => ****
        [BUTTONSOURCE] => IWD_SI_Other_OnePage
    )

[response] => Array
    (
        [PAL] => XXXXXXXXXX (-->Merchant ID)
        [LOCALE] => en_AU
        [TIMESTAMP] => 2017-06-22T02:18:31Z
        [CORRELATIONID] => 182c8e5d91387
        [ACK] => Success
        [VERSION] => 94.0
        [BUILD] => 29297572
    )

[__pid] => 7545
)
```

It states a success but is recorded as a bug.

What do I do to fix this?

I am using magento 1.9.3.3 and Paypal Website Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout)

The checkout allows guest checkout.

Enable SSL verification set to No.

Comment: Does it turn to any PHP exception error pages? Or the flow goes properly? Debug log does NOT always mean the module have bugs.

Comment: It continues on the flow.  But this bugs me. (sorry for the pun)

Comment: Are you in developer mode? Check the setting on System->Configuration ->Payment Methods (Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout)

Comment: @PYYick I have debug mode active due to my client telling me that Paypal orders are not being registered.  I don't know if this is the cause though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's NOT an error.

As you said that the flow is not interrupted, so I'm sure it's just a setting issue. You turned on the debug mode on Paypal so `var/log/debug.log` keep printing the data from Paypal. If this debug log caused you some annoyances, you can turn it off by  **System->Configuration ->Payment Methods (Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout)->Off**.

Comment: I turned on the logs to see where the error in paypal payments orders not getting registered is being generated.  Maybe it is a false flag.  I am currently investigating whether it may be due to the chron jobs.

Comment: Surely not related to CRON job. As I stated before, you're NOT encountering any problems. The debug log generates every time you use Paypal unless you turn off this setting.

Comment: So I assume I can safely ignore that success debug.  I just thought it was related to the paypal orders not being recorded error and if I fixed it then the paypal payment order would record properly.

Comment: Hurray, you got my point! You can move on to other tasks.